# How to create the formula: find value from column if equals another value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
A       0       C       100%
B       0       B       
C       ok      D       100%
D       ok              100%
E       no      A       
F       ok      F       100%
```

I want to create the formula to make the column 2 get the value from column1 and look it for in column 3 if it didn't find it, write no; if it found the value, look for the value in column4 if 100%, write ok, if didn't find 100%, write 0.

I hope you help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MATCH` to check if the value from column 1 is in column 3 (`MATCH` returns a number when there is a match, an error otherwise), then `VLOOKUP` to get the percentage, all within `IF` statements:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, C:C, 0)), IF(VLOOKUP(A2, C:D, 2, 0)=1, "ok", 0), "no")
```

The above assumes that the values in column 4 are numeric values formatted as percentages.

---

`VLOOKUP` works as follows:

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

`lookup_value` is the value you're searching.

`table_array` is the table in which the search will be performed and also from where the result will be pulled from. The `lookup_value` will be searched for in the first column of the `table_array`. The result will be pulled from the `col_index_num`th column in the `table_array`.

`[range_lookup]` will decide whether the search will be an exact search or an approximate search.

In the above formula, the `VLOOKUP` looks for the value from A2, into column C, and returns the corresponding value from the 2nd column in table C:D (i.e. from column D) and ensures that this is an exact search (0 means exact, 1 means approximate).

---

As per discussion with OP, turns out that Column1 and Column3 were 3 separate columns that needed to be checked for. Since `MATCH` and `VLOOKUP` can only check 1 column at a time (unless having recourse to array invocation), `COUNTIFS` would probably be more appropriate:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet3!$B$13:$B$289,E5,Sheet3!$C$13:$C$289,F5,Sheet3!$D$13:$D$289,G5)=0,"no",IF(SUMIFS(Sheet3!N$13:N$289,Sheet3!$B$13:$B$289,E5,Sheet3!$C$13:$C$289,F5,Sheet3!$D$13:$D$289,G5)=1,"ok",0))
```

The above formula is what I've come up with which I believe is working for the provided sample data.

Comment: I didn't understand the formula after VLOOKUP.
what's C:D ??? Is it column 3 and column 4??

Comment: Because I'm working on more than one sheet, the formula will be that:
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G384,Sheet3!D:D, 0)), IF(VLOOKUP(G384,Sheet3!D:D:Sheet3!N:N, 2, 0)=1, "ok", 0), "no")

but it gives me 0 ...and it should give me ok

Can you tell me why?? Is there something wrong in the formula.
In the sample workbook you attached it's working ok, but in my case no.

Comment: Thank you Jerry.. Now is working fine.
But I want to know why you changed 2 in VLOOKUP to 11 ??

Comment: Thank you Jerry.
Last question if I need the formula to match 2 times.
first: Match(G384,Sheet3!D:D, 0)
Second : Match(F384, Sheet3!C:C, 0)
Then
VLookup same..

Comment: When I used: =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G384,Sheet3!D:D, 0),ISNUMBER(MATCH(F384,Sheet3!C:C, 0))), IF(VLOOKUP(G384,Sheet3!D:N, 11, 0)=1, "ok", 0), "no") It gives me error: You've entered too many arguments for this function. and when I used the second function is not working good, because the results are always ok even the N column is empty not 100%.

Comment: :( I used last one: =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G384,Sheet3!D:D,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(F384,Sheet3!C:C,0))),‌​IF(VLOOKUP(G384,Sheet3!D:N,11,0)=1,"ok",0),"no")   .... But still error: We found a problem with this formula.

Comment: This what I wrote exactly ... copying and pasting:
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G384,Sheet3!D:D,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(F384,Sheet3!C:C,0))), ​​IF(VLOOKUP(G384,Sheet3!D:N,11,0)=1,"ok",0),"no")

Comment: It's seems ok in your file, but when I copied the formula in my sheet the results come always ok again.. I think the problem is because I don't use as you file the same value (B or A or C) what I mean: for example B in my file is not fixed value , but is changeable.So (in your file, sheet3) B (C3) in column C should be different from B (D3) in column D. 
Another point: B ( D3) equals same value of sheet1 (A3) and the another value  (C3) equals same value of sheet1 (-A3) that you didn't make it.
Understand me??

Comment: @WISSO Okay, I now see the problem and one of `VLOOKUP`s shortcoming is that it will take the value of the first matching cell. I see that you have `Test Pack No` as well. Would you like me to put that in the condition as well?

Comment: @WISSO Okay, I have put the file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/Pipe%20Inspection%20Control%20Sheet%20-%20FINAL.xlsx). I tried to avoid array formulas (which make the calculation take more time) and restricted the range to what was required, but you will need to change them when/if more data comes in. If that works for you, I'll update my answer and delete all the comments here except this one to clean up.

Comment: Yes That's what I need.. I'll change something, but it's perfectly.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: There's another point in the same file, Jerry.
I want to fill Sheet3 automatically in columns B, C, D, G and H.

Comment: There's another point in the same file, Jerry.
I want to fill Sheet3 automatically in columns B, C, D, G and H.
Column B (Sheet3) = Column E(Sheet2), Column C (Sheet3) = Column F(Sheet2), Column D(Sheet3)=Column G(Sheet2), Column G(Sheet3)=Column C(Sheet2), Column H(Sheet3)=Column D(Sheet2)
I want when I write new row in Sheet2, the formula looks for if the values exist (5 columns) in Sheet3, If YES, nothing to do, If don't exist, the values became copied in new row in Sheet3.
I hope you understood me and help me for that.
Thanks

Comment: @WISSO Hi! Sorry, I opened this page in a tab and forgot it on my desktop (I usually work on my laptop so..) I'm not sure I fully understand and from the looks of it, you could have circular reference errors (Sheet3 depends on Sheet2 for input, but sheet2 again refers to Sheet3). Hmm, does that mean that initially, Sheet3 only have headers?

Comment: no problem. But the both of sheets depend on other in some columns. Sheets3 will only filled manually in columns: N, O, P ....etc.

Comment: @WISSO Do you know how many rows you're going to have in Sheet3, or at least, know the maximum number of foreseeable rows?

Comment: No unfortunately unlimited.

Comment: @WISSO It won't be practical with formulas then, because with formulas, that means you will have to fill the entire columns with formulas and that will cause your workbook to horribly slow down for each little calculation... :(

Comment: @WISSO You can make it work with formulas, but it will take a lot of time each time you add a row because of the number of formulas required.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of a countif function. If you format your data as a table with the headers "Column1", "Column2", etc., then you can use a formula like this in Column2

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Column3],[@Column1])>0,IF([@Column4]=1,"ok",0),"no")
```

What we're doing is counting the number of instances of the first column (let's say "A") in the third column. If we find more than one instance (>0), then this expression evaluates to true.

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Column3],[@Column1])>0,
```

That takes us to the second "IF" statement where we check if the row that matches ours is equal to 1 (100% in percentage terms), and if that is true, we put "ok" in our cell. If that is not true (but we did find a reference to "A"), then we put 0 in our cell.

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Column3],[@Column1])>0,IF([@Column4]=1,"ok",0
```

And of course, if we didn't find "A" in the first place, we just put "no" in our cell.

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Column3],[@Column1])>0,IF([@Column4]=1,"ok",0),"no")
```

If this is a simple range, then your formula for the first cell in Column2 would look lie this

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$7,A2),IF(D2=1,"ok",0),"no")
```

Cell 2 would look like this...

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$7,A3),IF(D3=1,"ok",0),"no")
```

etc, etc. If the "100%" is stored as text in your last column, then you can just set the second "IF" statement to look for the text "100%" instead of the number 1.

**EDIT:** It seems I have misunderstood the question slightly. I have left my original answers above for reference. Here are revised formulas that will provide the correct results.

Table:

```
=IF(COUNTIF([Column3],[@Column1]),IF(COUNTIFS([Column3],[@Column1],[Column4],1)>0,"ok",0),"no")
```

So quickly covering the changes. Basically, by using the countifs, we are now counting all cells that equal our match (let's say "A") and also have 100% in the last column. If the count of these is greater than 0, we put "ok", otherwise 0.

```
IF(COUNTIFS([Column3],[@Column1],[Column4],1)>0,"ok",0)
```

Range:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C$2:$C$7,A2),IF(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,A2,$D$2:$D$7,1)>0,"ok",0),"no")
```

Of course, this may not be as elegant as [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx), but hopefully it at least provides an alternative way to approach the problem.

References: [excel if](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx), [excel countif](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx), [excel operators](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-calculation-operators-HP005198697.aspx), [excel tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-excel-tables-HA010048546.aspx), [excel countifs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)

Comment: From the first link of your answer: "If **FALSE**, VLOOKUP will only find an exact match. In this case, the values in the first column of table_array **do not need to be sorted**."

Comment: Furthermore, you cannot use `D2=1` because the corresponding value may not necessarily be directly to the right of the value in column A.

Comment: @Jerry, yes, I see that now, I apologize for the misleading statement on VLOOKUP and will edit my post. I'm sorry I also misunderstood the 100% functionality, I didn't check my answer closely enough. Will edit.

Comment: @p0werenner, thanks for the encouragement, sorry I was a bit off on the answer :-)

Comment: @StephenH Thank you for your explanation, but still not working.

Comment: @Jerry, I have added the corrected implementation using countifs for the second lookup. It seems VLOOKUP is definitely a cleaner way to implement this, but I guess this is just a second way to approach the problem. As a matter of presentation, should I remove the original part of my post and insert the new formulas above to avoid confusion?

Comment: @WISSO, I have added corrected formulas that show how to perform your functions using countifs, but it seems Jerry's VLOOKUP solution might be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,0),1)=1,"NO",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,0)=1,"OK",0))`